# Does the dependent clause modify both independent clauses in a compound-complex sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he rented the latest
>   spy thriller, and he enjoyed it very much.

Would this sentence mean this:

> Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he rented the latest
>   spy thriller. He enjoyed it very much.

Or this:

> Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he rented the latest
>   spy thriller. Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he
>   enjoyed it very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting example.  But I don't think it is split up at all -- the "though" clause modifies the conjunction of two sentences:

> [Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, [he rented the latest spy thriller, and he enjoyed it very much] ].

Suppose, instead of the "though" clause modifier, we had the sentence modifier "probably":

> Probably, Mitchell rented the latest spy thriller, and enjoyed it very much.

Here, the ordinary interpretation would be that it is the conjunction of the events of renting and enjoying that is probable, though either of the events alone might be improbable.  So it is possible to modify a coordinate structure in a way that does not reduce to modifying either part or both parts individually.

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, I believe the first way to split it is better:

> Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he rented the latest
>   spy thriller. He enjoyed it very much.

Another option is this:

> Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he rented the latest spy thriller and enjoyed it very much.

The second "he" in the original sentence can be removed because there is no ambiguity to whom the word "he" is referring.